# How to run `clang-apply-replacements` on change set generated by `clang-tidy --export-fixes`?

Tags: clang-tidy

Command `clang-tidy --export-fixes=fixes.yml <sources>` generates a file `fixes.yml` with stances like

```
---
Diagnostics:
  - DiagnosticName:  modernize-loop-convert
    DiagnosticMessage:
      Message:         use range-based for loop instead
      FilePath:        'Base/Util/StringUtils.cpp'
      FileOffset:      1510
      Replacements:
        - FilePath:        'Base/Util/StringUtils.cpp'
          Offset:          1514
          Length:          37
          ReplacementText: '(const auto & item : items)'
    Level:           Warning
    BuildDirectory:  'tidy/Base'
```

which looks entirely reasonable.

How to apply these changes to the sources? `man clang-apply-replacements` says

```
USAGE: clang-apply-replacements [options] <Search Root Directory>
```

None of the options are pertinent. Some web sources tell us we have just to put the change set into the root directory, which will be searched for any `.yml` file.

Doesn't work for me: `clang-apply-replacements .` executes instantaneously, prints no message, and effectuates no changes.

Answer (score 3):

I had the exact same issue. Simply change the extension of your fixes file to `.yaml`

`clang-apply-replacements` won't find your files if they use `.yml`